# Parametrizing a given curve (semi-circle)?

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have to parametrize the upper half-disk (upper semi-circle connecting x = -1 to x = 1).  This is in the context of finding the contour integral of $f(z) = \sqrt(r)e^{i\theta/2}$ over this upper half disk.

We're given that the boundary of this half-disk is $0\leq r \leq 1, 0\leq \theta \leq \pi$.  So basically I want to give a formula for z over a certain range of values so it will trace out the upper half disk.

We can break this up into three parts.  Suppose I start with the segment from x = -1 to x = 1.  If I were doing this normally, I'd just say:

z(t) = t for $-1 \leq t \leq 0$.

Thoughts?

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to break this into two parts. If you start at $z=1$, you can use $z=e^{it}$ for $0\leq t\leq \pi$, which takes you to $z=-1$ along the top of the semi-circle. Then you can parameterize the segment from $-1$ back to $1$ however you like, such as $z=t$ for $-1\leq t\leq 1$.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: But don't I have to parametrize it in terms of $r$ or $\theta$ so I can take the contour integral?